# How to receive json result using jquery ajax?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791651/how-do-i-receive-a-json-file-using-ajax-and-parse-it-using-javascript), but with no luck. When I use the following link in the address bar, the browser shows json data.

`http://xxxx.xxx.com:1234/products.json`  // Only a sample link

But when I try the following code,

```
 $.ajax({

                url : 'http://xxxx.xxx.com:1234/products.json',

                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {

                alert( "test" ); 


                },
                error : function() {
                    alert("Sorry, The requested property could not be found.");
                }
            });
```

It always shows the error message. What is wrong in my method?

Comment: Have you run the JSON through a validator like JSON Lint, to check it is 100% valid?

Comment: do you control the content?

Comment: You cannot fetch content from other domains unless the other domain explicitly allows it, and that site probably doesn't. (The link doesn't work anyway.)

Comment: change your error handler to `    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("Error:" + status + ':' + error + ':' + xhr.responseText);
    }`

Comment: If server allows it, use jsonp

Comment: also check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: What is the exact error text? I'm expecting to see something along the lines of `ACCESS DENIED SAME ORIGIN POLICY` when using json.

Comment: @Sharun that means the server you are requesting from doesn't support JSONP. If it also isn't doing CORS, then you're only option is to use something other than the browser to make the request (such as your server)

Comment: Right, but JSON data is not JSONP. There is no way to access that data in javascript.

Comment: Because you ***can't*** access the contents of a script tag pointing to an external script.

Comment: Yes, you should send the request to a script on your server, then have your server go get the json.

Comment: What server-side language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)