# My code wont print my object

Tags: javascript

When I try to print my object it gives me no response.

```
var steaminv = JSON.parse("http://steamcommunity.com/id/pootel/inventory/json/730/2.json");
document.write(steaminv);
```

Comment: You're trying to parse the string `"http://steamcommunity.com/id/pootel/inventory/json/730/2.json"`, you never actually requested the JSON file.

Comment: @Jyeon how would i request the JSON file?

Comment: Where did you get the idea from that it would be possible to pass a URL to `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @FelixKling from php

Comment: PHP doesn't have `JSON.parse`. The equivalent is `json_decode`, which doesn't accept a URI either. Also PHP and JavaScript are different languages. If you are trying out an unfamiliar method, [read its documentation first!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should request the file first and then parse the content of the file.

`JSON.parse` requires a json object encoded as string. It does not request the file for you.

If you are using node, you can use [request](https://github.com/request/request) module. If you are using javascript on browser, you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and do an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to get the content of the file.

Please take a look at this question: [How do I receive a JSON file using AJAX and parse it using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791651/how-do-i-receive-a-json-file-using-ajax-and-parse-it-using-javascript)

Just to give you an idea what `JSON.parse` does:

```
var str = '{"name":"Amir","age":25}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj.name);
console.log(obj.age);
```